# Laravel 4 (+ Datatables) route works intermittently

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4, datatable

I am working with Datatables to show plenty of rows thus I decided to use server side processing. I am working with Laravel 4 on the back-end.

The problem is very *very* **very** weird.

*Every time* I refresh the page where the table is, the AJAX request to the server *works* **however** if I replay the same XHR request (with Google Dev Tools) or even just doing any other action (ie. sorting, searching) the route **MAY NOT** work (note carefully, I have used *may* because it's really random).

This is the route:

```php
Route::group(['before' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::get('announcements', 'AnnouncementsAPIController@getAnnouncements');
});
```

This is the controller:

```php
class AnnouncementsAPIController extends BaseController {

    public function getAnnouncements()
    {
        $queries = $this->request->query('queries');

        $office = (isset($queries['office']) === true) 
            ? Office::find(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $queries['office'])) 
            : Office::find(Auth::user()->office->id);

        $builder = $office->announcements();

        $columns = [
            'announcements.id',
            'announcements.extractor_task_id',
            'announcements.user_id',
            'announcements.office_id',
            'announcements.phone_status',
            'announcements.phone_recall',
            'announcements.created_at',
            'announcements.name',
            'announcements.phone',
            'announcements.date',
            'announcements.trademark',
            'announcements.model',
            'announcements.price',
            'announcements.city',
            'announcements.kilometers',
            'announcements.crmstate',
            'announcements.extractor_updated_at'
        ];

        $announcements = Datatablefy::prepare($builder, 'Announcement', ['columns' => $columns], Input::all());
        $announcements = $announcements->datatablefy();
        return $announcements->make(true);
    }

}
```

This is an example URL that Datatables generates:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/announcements?draw=7&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=website&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=id&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=date&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=city&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=trademark&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=model&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=price&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=name&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B8%5D%5Bdata%5D=phone&columns%5B8%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B8%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B9%5D%5Bdata%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B9%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B10%5D%5Bdata%5D=crmstate&columns%5B10%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B10%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B11%5D%5Bdata%5D=welcome_email&columns%5B11%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B11%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B12%5D%5Bdata%5D=user_id&columns%5B12%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B12%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B13%5D%5Bdata%5D=&columns%5B13%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B13%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B13%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=2&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1426180688420
```

Which sometimes may randomly give:

```
{
    "error": {
        "type": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
        "message": "",
        "file": "path\\to\\application\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
        "line": 148
    }
}
```

Something even more weird is that using the route *without* any query string, it *always* works.

Something I have also noted is that if I try to decode the URL and use it, it automatically forces me out the website, logging me out.

Here's the questions:

- How do I fix the issue?
- Why does the query string give issues?
- Why using a decoded URL it forces me to logout?

Comment: Does firing *exactly* the same query string *sometimes* throw an error - or is it *some* query strings only? If you can work out which is true - that will make a big difference. My guess is a certain combination in a specific query string is breaking the routing process. You should see if you can find a specific string which always breaks - then we can debug it from there...

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not so I cannot really debug which query string gives issues.

Comment: You'll need to log all the queries until you find out which ones break it. Otherwise no one here is going to be able to help unfortunately...

Comment: @TheShiftExchange The thing is that there is not a specific query that breaks it. It is very random. A query that works at first may not work second, and a query that doesn't work first may work second. It's very weird.

Comment: Strangely changing environment the problem does not occur anymore. What may cause this issue?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your sessions then. What session driver are you using?

Comment: I use the default *file* driver of Laravel.

Comment: So does your server has redis or memcache? Could you switch to that?

Comment: I have changed local environment. Using my personal computer it didn't work while using the office's computer it works. Very strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72943/discussion-between-giampy-and-the-shift-exchange).